# PhoneJS: how to add logo in navi list

Tags: html, phonejs

I am new PhoneJS coder. i have created simple slideout code.

I wanting that how to add logo at top in navi list view.

[image]

In picture, u can see red cirlce. that place how we can add logo? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In file **layouts/SlideOut/SlideOutLayout.js** you can find layout controller code.

Here in the end of the method **_createNavigation** put your code adding logotype to slideout:

```
_createNavigation : function(navigationCommands) {
    // existing code goes here

    this.$slideOut.find(".dx-slideout-menu").prepend("<div class='logo'>My Logo Here</div>");
}
```

Of course you can put any markup you need. In my example the logo could be background of the div.logo.

Comment: I Would like to add an image with size?

Comment: You can add whatever you wish. Just put your markup in prepend call. this.$slideOut.find(".dx-slideout-menu").prepend("<img src='my-logo-url' style='width:100px; height:100px;' />")